# I have a problemi with scroll

Tags: java, android, scrollview

[scroll-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuKfu.jpg). Hi, what code should I use to make the scroll can only be used in space with visible objects? For example if `textwiew` set visibile the space that you can use increase

Comment: maybe if you set the scrollview height to wrap_content?

Comment: no, I mean to make the sroll scribble only if there are visible objects. for example if at the beginning there are 4 visible textwiews and 4 non-bistable textwiews, I can only scroll the part with the visible ones and only when the other textwiews become visible I can also scroll on them

Comment: i know what you mean. if you WRAP_CONTENT for the scroll view, then it will wrap around the views that are visable.... try it in code.

Comment: even if I insert a linearview inside the scroll?